# Using groovy script in active choices reactive parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I'm using jenkins 2.x and I'm trying to run a groovy script into active choices reactive parameter. but only the fallback script is running.

### Groovy script:

```
 def myUrl ="https://vfoms-seu.trivadis.com/nexus/repository/nexus_repos/com/trivadis/oms/OutputManagement/maven-metadata.xml"
def data = new URL(myUrl)
def content = data.getText()

def dataObj = new XmlParser().parseText(content )
def versionsNr
for (v in dataObj.versioning[0].versions[0].version){
  versionsNr.add(v.text())
}
return [versionsNr]
```

### Fallback script:

```
return["Error"]
```

Choices type single select

can you help me to fine out my issue?!

Comment: Did you test the code outside of Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def dataObj = new XmlSlurper().parse("https://vfoms-seu.trivadis.com/nexus/repository/nexus_repos/com/trivadis/oms/OutputManagement/maven-metadata.xml")

List<String> versionsNr=[]
for (v in dataObj.versioning.versions.version){
  versionsNr.add(v.text())
}
return versionsNr
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my url :)
My code works